# Why race condition is only solved with ReentrantLock and not synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, synchronized

I try to use multi-threads to add all elements to my result list. I am not sure why the result looks weird.

```
public class PrintMessage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintMessage p = new PrintMessage();
        List<String> list = List.of("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h");

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        p.printValue(list, executor);
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        executor.shutdown();

        System.out.println(res);
    }

    //ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private volatile int index = 0;
    static List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

    class Printer implements Runnable {
        List<String> list;

        public Printer(List<String> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //lock.lock();
           
            pickItem(index, list);
            //increment();
            //lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void increment() {
        index++;
    }
    private synchronized void pickItem(int index, List<String> list) {
        res.add(list.get(index));
        increment();
    }
    public void printValue(List<String> list, ExecutorService executor) {

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            executor.submit(new Printer(list));
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure why does the index not change by other threads,  when I change **synchronized** and use **ReentrantLock** to lock pick(), increment() methods. the result looks good. Can someone explain the reason? Many thanks.

`[a, b, c, e, e, f, a, a]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure why does the index not change by other threads, when I change
> synchronized and use ReentrantLock to lock pick(), increment()
> methods. the result looks good. Can someone explain the reason? Many
> thanks.

The `synchronized` on the method

```
private synchronized void pickItem(int index, List<String> list) {
    res.add(list.get(index));
    increment();
}
```

is locking using the *implicit* lock of the object instance returned by `this` of the class `Printer`, and since for each `Thread` a new object instance of a the `Printer` class is created:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    executor.submit(new Printer(list));
}
```

each thread is calling `synchronized` on different instances of the class `Printer`. Hence, those threads are **not locking using the same `lock`, and consequently there is a *race-condition***.

However, the `lock` variable

```
ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
```

is a field variable of the Object `PrintMessage`, **which is shared among all threads**. Therefore, when threads invoke `lock.lock();` and `lock.unlock();` they are using the same (shared) lock, and consequently, there is no longer the aforementioned *race-condition*.

The `ReentrantLock` alone (without the `synchronized` on the method `pickItem`) solves the aforementioned *race-condition*.